# How can I write out header names along with data using dlmwrite?

Tags: matlab, csv

I use this code to write out to a csv file inside a loop. The loop will run thousands of times and store these 5 data points after every run.

```
dlmwrite('test.csv', [outlet_info.outlet_row, outlet_info.outlet_col,
         outlet_info.rel_err, outlet_info.new_est_darea, delta1)
```

1. How can I put header names in the csv file as well? eg. row, col, err, area, del
2. How can I append 5 new data as a new row after every loop? How do I use append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fprintf to write the header as a single line into the file. 
Then use dlmwrite to append data to it:

```
filename = 'test.csv';
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
fprintf(fid, 'HEADER LINE HERE...\n');
fclose(fid)

for i = ... %(loop over your data here...)
   dlmwrite(filename, [outlet_info.outlet_row, outlet_info.outlet_col,
     outlet_info.rel_err, outlet_info.new_est_darea, delta1], '-append', 'precision', '%.6f', 'delimiter', ';');
end
```

Comment: Where should I put this info? (outlet_info.outlet_row, outlet_info.outlet_col,
         outlet_info.rel_err, outlet_info.new_est_darea, delta1)

Comment: I changed my example to match your request

Comment: I think the delimiter should be ','. Works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with using `dlmwrite` only. Just write the header first an then use the `-append` flag to append to it:

```
%prepare your header string
hdr = 'row, col, err, area, del';
%write header first
dlmwrite('test.csv', hdr, '');
%append your data to the same file 
dlmwrite('test.csv', [outlet_info.outlet_row, outlet_info.outlet_col,
         outlet_info.rel_err, outlet_info.new_est_darea, delta1, '-append');
```